# How to perform for loop inside backticks in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I have group by an array of elements based on their resturant id.

```
function grouparray(list,key)
   {
       return list.reduce(function(rv,x){
           (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
           return rv;
       },{});
   };
   var group = grouparray(cartArray,"resturantid");
```

it gives an output like

```
{1: Array(3), 2: Array(3)}
```

It is array inside an array.

now i want to loop this inside backticks
Full Code:

```
function displaycheckout()
{
    var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();

   function grouparray(list,key)
   {
       return list.reduce(function(rv,x){
           (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
           return rv;
       },{});
   };
   var group = grouparray(cartArray,"resturantid");

    for(i in group)
    {

         output +=
         ` Resturant Name : ${group[i][0].resturant}
         `
         for(a in group[i]){
          `
            menu ${group[i][a].food}
          `
      }
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Please don"t tagged not related tag

Comment: @Tushar group[ i ] is the main loop inside that loop there is resturant menus.

Comment: try modify this:  for(let i of group)

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).  Please post the input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#map` on `Object.values`.

```
output +=
         ` Resturant Name : ${group[i][0]}
          ${Object.values(group[i]).map(({food})=>"Menu " + food).join("\n")}
         `
```